# Optimum Strategy

Tags: permutations, game-theory

In a Given we have a numbers in the Range `L and R`

During each turn, a player can choose any number (regardless of whether or not it was chosen during a previous turn) in the inclusive range `L` between `R`  and.

The game ends when the running sum of chosen numbers (i.e., sum of all numbers chosen by `both` players) is greater than `K`, and the last player to take their turn wins.

So which player win First or Second ?

Comment: The answer depends on $L$, $R$ and $K$.

Comment: So Can you express the answer in terms of L , R and KK

Comment: @5xum I guess `(K-L)/(R-L)` is even  so First Wins

Comment: (K-L)/(R-L) doesn't need to be an integer, how can we talk about it being even?

Comment: so any answer from your side

Comment: In a Given... what? And for winning: You mean that the player who exceeds $K$ wins?

Comment: @JimmyR. ., sum of all numbers chosen by both players) is greater than K, and the last player to take their turn wins.

Comment: A ok, I see, now, thanks for repeating exactly the body of your question. Now, I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends.

For example, if $L+R > K > R$, then clearly, player two wins, since he chooses $R$, and player $1$ chose at least $L$, so the sum is at least $L+R$.

If $L=R$, then the game is entirely deterministic, and the result depends on whether $\left\lfloor \frac KL\right\rfloor$ is even or odd.

I don't see an easy answer for the general case of $L, R, K$, however.

Comment: what happen when `K>(L+R)`

Comment: Find this Article [article](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55980.html)